# Generate interleavings of two strings in lexicographical order in Python

Tags: python-3.x, permutation, backtracking, lexicographic

How to generate interleavings of two strings in lexicograhical order in python?

I was able to generate interleavings, but not in lexicographical order.

The input given was,

Input :

2

nkb gl

bn zh

Expected output:

Case #1:
glnkb
gnkbl
gnklb
gnlkb
ngkbl
ngklb
nglkb
nkbgl
nkgbl
nkglb

Case #2:
bnzh
bzhn
bznh
zbhn
zbnh
zhbn

This is my code --

```
def interleave(A,B,ans,m,n,idx):
    if m == 0 and n == 0:
        print("".join(ans))
        return 
    if len(A)<=len(B):
        if m!=0:
            ans[idx]=A[0]
            interleave(A[1:],B,ans,m-1,n,idx+1)
        if n!=0:
            ans[idx]=B[0]
            interleave(A,B[1:],ans,m,n-1,idx+1)
    else:
        if n!=0:
            ans[idx]=B[0]
            interleave(A,B[1:],ans,m,n-1,idx+1)
        if m!=0:
            ans[idx]=A[0]
            interleave(A[1:],B,ans,m-1,n,idx+1)
t=int(input())
count=0
for i in range(t):
    count+=1
    print("Case #%d:"%count)
    A,B=input().split()
    m,n=len(A),len(B)
    ans=['']*(m+n)
    idx=0
    interleave(A,B,ans,m,n,idx)
```

Output of the code that I wrote was--

```
Case #1:
glnkb
gnlkb
gnkbl
gnklb
nkbgl
nkgbl
nkglb
nglkb
ngkbl
ngklb
Case #2:
bnzh
bznh
bzhn
zhbn
zbnh
zbhn
```

There is some problem in the logic. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: Yes, I found the approach.
Instead of comparing the length of the two strings at each and every recursive call we need to compare the ascii value of the characters in those strings.